# How to get Fault detail in ChannelFactory<TChannel>.Faulted

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm writing some code for a WCF ChannelFactory Manager. My question comes from the event " ChannelFactory.Faulted": Both parameter ("object sender" and "EventArgs args" ) contain no info about the original fualt, How can I get ChannelFactory Fault detail in a customized fault handler?

```
   private ChannelFactory CreateFactoryInstance<T>(string endpointConfigurationName, string endpointAddress)
    {
        ChannelFactory factory = null;
        factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(endpointConfigurationName, new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress));
        //Customizing Factory Fault handler
        factory.Faulted += FactoryFaulted;
        factory.Open();
        return factory;
    }

    private void FactoryFaulted(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        ChannelFactory factory = (ChannelFactory)sender;            
        factory.Close();
        //...
        //How can I get more Fault detail, so as to throw a meaningful Exception?
        throw new ApplicationException("Failure in ChannelFactory ");
    }
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a brief look around with ILSpy and `ChannelFactory` derives from `CommunicationObject` which can transition into a faulted state when an exception is thrown during `Open`/`BeginOpen`. So try/catch around `Open` will catch at least some of the possible errors. Not sure if there are other places where the channel factory can get into faulted state. Note that the `Faulted` event handler is called in the finally block which means it is called before you catch the exception.

Comment: Thank you. So if I stop throwing new Exception in my customized fault handler (FactoryFaulted) , the original exception will be available to the caller.

Comment: @Whitesmell: Seems like it. Attach to the `Opened` or `Opening` event handler and throw a `FatalException` in there, this should bubble up (only fatal exceptions inside event handler bubble up).